# Share The Same Session in Java Web Application

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

i'm facing a problem with http session in my web application. i'm using glassfish server as a web server.

my problem is that i can't share the same session in my web application. in otherwise , i have create a session in HomePage.jsp and when i go to any servlet and trying to add data to this session it's return null or create a new session.

what i know that the session created on running any web application a default session is generated and could be used all over this web Application. But in this case,i dont know why this is happening with me.

please can anyone help me and show me how i can fix it. 
best regards :)

Comment: Sharing sessions can lead to all sorts of security issues. What exactly are you trying to share between sessions? Maybe you could implement some sort of caching mechanism and share your data through there.

Comment: The session is actually shared between JSP pages and servlets in the same web application. Do you enable cookies in the browser? Do you get the same sessions across JSP pages? What is the code you use to get the session in the servlet? Show us more code

Comment: this is the code that i use in HomePage.jsp(this the first page that is shown when i run the project)if (session == request.getSession(false) ) {
          System.out.println("session alerady Exist : "+session.getId()); 
           
        }
        else{
          
           session = request.getSession(true);
        }  and in the servlet i'm using  HttpSession session=request.getSession();String UserName=request.getParameter("UserName"); session.setAttribute("UserName",UserName);

Comment: the problem in servlet a new session is created and if i use request.getSession(false) nullpointerExc is returned

Comment: Plus i'm using cookies to store data from homePage so cookies are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In JSP pages, if you specify the attribute `session=true` in the `page` directive, you will have a variable called `session` that will have value automatically. If you don't specify it, you have to get the session in the JSP page explicitly by calling `request.getSession();`. In the servlet, there is no automatique `session` variable. You have to access the session like this in the servlet:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("UserName",UserName);
```

Comment: hello, yes im doing it like you said. but request.getsession() create a new session and dont use the existing session. i dont know why this is happening. this is not my first project and i'm always working with session like you have mentioned... so i'm rely confused :(

Comment: Are you manipulating cookies manually? You said above: "Plus i'm using cookies to store data from homePage so cookies are enabled". I think you are messing up the cookies. This is why you loose the session. Trace the cookies arrived to the JSP page and the servlet. Maybe you introduce a small syntax problem in the cookies? In general, you loose the session when you loose the cookie.

Comment: yes im manipulating cookies manually.  here how i add data to cookies foundCookie=false; for(int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {Cookie cookie1 = cookies[i];if (cookie1.getName().equals("EsitimatedPV")) {Cookie1.setValue(Valueee);cookie1.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10);cookie1.setPath("/"); response.addCookie(cookie1); foundCookie = true;
            }  }if (!foundCookie) {Cookie cookie1 = new Cookie("EsitimatedPV", Valueee); cookie1.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10);cookie1.setPath("/"); response.addCookie(cookie1); 
        }

Comment: Comment out the cookies manipulation and test if you get the session in the servlet.

Comment: this code i use it in other servlet not in servlet where i facing problems...but i wanna make sure if i'm adding data correctly . maybe i can resolve the session problem

Comment: I meant that you temporarily remove the code that modifies the coockies, even if it is in another servlet., and see if you get the session correctly. Once the cookie becomes bad in a servlet, it will affect the other servlets.